# Finding the transformation matrix given the transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I'm given the Transformation $P(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_2,x_3)$, and I'm supposed to find the transformation matrix $A$ so that $A (x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_2,x_3)$.

How do I do this? I managed to find it for a previous question through trial and error but it took me a while and I need a good mathematical way to do it.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general method is to find where the standard basis vectors are mapped.  So first find $\vec a = P(1,0,0)$, $\vec b = P(0,1,0)$, and $\vec c = P(0,0,1)$.  The matrix which describes this transformation will then be $$\begin{bmatrix} \vec a & \vec b & \vec c \end{bmatrix}$$ where $\vec a, \vec b,$ and $\vec c$ are column vectors.

Here's why:  Let $$A = \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\end{bmatrix}$$

Then $A\hat e_1 = \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}a_{11} + 0 + 0 \\ a_{21} + 0 + 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} \\ a_{21} \end{bmatrix}$.  Likewise $A\hat e_2 = \begin{bmatrix} a_{12} \\ a_{22} \end{bmatrix}$ and $A\hat e_3 = \begin{bmatrix} a_{13} \\ a_{23} \end{bmatrix}$.

Thus all we need to do to specify our matrix is find how it transforms the standard basis vectors because each of those vectors will be the columns of the matrix.

Answer (score 2):

The columns of the transformation are the result of applying $P$ to the standard basis vectors. The first column, for example, is $p\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

It helps to think of the transformation as follows:
$$
P (x_1,x_2,x_3) = \pmatrix{0x_1 + 1x_2 + 0x_3\\0x_1 + 0x_2 + 1x_3}
$$
So, what matrix $A$ will satisfy
$$
A \pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\x_3} = \pmatrix{0x_1 + 1x_2 + 0x_3\\0x_1 + 0x_2 + 1x_3}?
$$